# How to model relationship using event sourcing

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

In our scenario, we have a Course entity to represent course content. For each student attending a course, there is a CourseSession entity representing the learning progress of the student in the course. So there is a one-to-many relationship between Course and CourseSession. If using relational database, there will be a course table and course_session table, in which course has a unique ID and course session is uniquely identified by (courseId + studentId). We try to model this using event sourcing, and our event table is like following

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| entity_type | entity_id | event_type | event_data |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

this is fine for storing course, there is a courseId we can use as entity_id. But for CourseSession, there isn't an intrinsic id attribute, we have to use the concatenation of (courseId + studentId) as entity_id, which is not quite natural. Is there a better way to model this kind of relationship?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not an expert, so take this answer with a grain of salt

---

> But for CourseSession, there isn't an intrinsic id attribute, we have
> to use the concatenation of (courseId + studentId) as entity_id, which
> is not quite natural

It's normal to have a composite ID, and sometimes recommended, to keep your domain model aligned with the domain language.

The composite ID can be modeled as Value Object: `CourseSessionId { CoursId: string, studentId: string }.`

In addition to this domain-specific ID, you may need to add a **surrogate ID** to the entity to satisfy some infra requirements:

- Some ORMs force to have a numeric sequence ID
- Some Key-value stores require a ULID Key
- Short and user-friendly ID

The surrogate ID is an infra detail and must be hidden as much as possible from the domain layer.

---

> Is there a better way to model this kind of relationship?

The event sourcing pattern I saw in the DDD context suggests having a stream of events per aggregate.

In DDD, an **aggregate** can be considered as:

- A subsystem within the bounded context
- It has boundaries and invariants to protect its state
- It’s represented by an entity (aggregate root) and can contain other entities and value-objects.

If you consider that **CourseSession** entity belongs to **Course aggregate**, then you should keep using course ID as `entity_id` (or `aggregate_id`) for both Course and CourseSession related events.

in this case, the write model (main model) can easily build and presents the relationship Course / CourseSessions by playing the Course stream.

Otherwise, you must introduce a read model, and define a **projector** that will subscribe to both **Course** and **CourseSession** streams, and build the needed views.

This read model can be queried directly or by **Course** and **CourseSession** aggregates’ commands to take decisions, but keep in mind that’s often **eventually consistent**, and your business should tolerate that.

Answer (score 0):

Event sourcing is a different way of thinking about data. So the 'old' ways of thinking in terms of relationships don't really translate like that.

So the first point is that an event store isn't a table structure. It is a list of things that have happened in your system. The fact a student spent time on a course is a thing which happened.

If you want/need to access the data in relationships like you describe the easiest thing to do is to create a projection from the events which creates the data in the table form you are looking for.

However, as the projection is not the source of truth, why not think about creating de-normalised tables so you the database won't need to do any joins or other more complex jobs and your data will already be shaped as you need it for use in your application. This leads to super fast highly efficient read models.

Your users will thank you!